# Ударение в фамилиях современных писательниц

Tags: ударение

Как правильно ставить ударение в фамилиях - Знаменская, Вильмонт, Дашкова?

Answer (score 1):

Конечно, любая фамилия - это личное дело ее обладателя, и ударения там могут быть самые непредсказуемые, но, по логике, в фамилии Знаменская ударение должно ставиться на первое А. У Вильмонт зависит от происхождения фамилии. Честно говоря, достоверных сведений я об этом не нашла. Если фамилия английского происхождения, то ударение на первый слог. Если французского, то на последний. Тут можно провести аналогию с фамилией Бальмонт. Сам Константин Бальмонт делал в своей фамилии ударение на О. Наверное, у Вильмонт тот же случай.
С Дашковой также можно провести аналогию с Екатериной Дашковой, директора Петербургской Академии наук, у которой ударение в фамилии ставилось на первый слог.

Comment: С Бальмонтом сложно. Свидетельства противоречивы, наверняка нельзя сказать, какой ударение он предпочитал. Впрочем, это только свидетельствует, что не стоит искать какого-то правила.

А фамилия у него совсем не французская. Возможно - шотландская. Как и у Лермонтова. Или, под другой версии, переделанная русско-польская.

см. тут (раздел "семья") https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%2C_%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD_%D0%94%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87